# How to check for self collision when analyzing workspace of a 6R robot on Drake?

Tags: drake

Is there a way to check for self collisions on Drake? Suppose we iteratively set the joints of a 6R robot to some positions, could we check if two links of the robot are colliding with each other in that configuration? Does `ComputePointPairPenetration()` work with distinct entities or also with different links a robot?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use the `SceneGraph` api directly (e.g. `ComputePointPairPenetration`). But you should also take a look at the [`CollisionChecker`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1planning_1_1_collision_checker.html) interface.  It makes some of those queries (and others useful in motion planning) very easy, in addition to supporting parallelism.